# Translation of "I rest my case"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, modismos

In English, the phrase "I rest my case" can be used in a conversation by one person whose point has just been proven by the other person. In a legal sense, it would mean that a lawyer has concluded their argument, but in an idiomatic sense it can be used more generally. For example:

> **A**: You eat *way* too much during the day. You need to go on a diet.
>
> **B**: That's not true. I only have breakfast, brunch, lunch, dinner, and 4-5 snacks during the day.
>
> **A**: I rest my case.

Is there a similar idiom or phrase used in these situations in Spanish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a lot of movies is translated as *No tengo más preguntas* or *No hay más preguntas*.
“I rest my case” is used formally in court, and even in that case is often translated in such manner because the lawyer saying that stops asking questions to the witness.

> **A**: Comes mucho durante el día. ¿No deberías hacer dieta?
>
> **B**: ¡No es cierto!, Sólo desayuno, almuerzo, como, ceno y tomo 4 ó 5 aperitivos a lo largo del día.
>
> **A**: No tengo más preguntas. *(sarcasm)*

Comment: yeah, "No más preguntas" makes perfect sense and causes the same response as "I rest my case" in every aspect --> Sarcasm/End of discussion

Comment: [In a lot of movies, **it** is translation as etc.]

Comment: Así declaro. Diria yo.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the context. In your example you could use:

- Comes demasiado, deberías hacer dieta.
- No es cierto. Sólo desayuno, meriendo, como, ceno y tomo 4 o 5 tentempiés al día.
- Pues eso/ Lo que te decía/ ¿Y eso no es mucho? (Ironic)/ Tú mismo la has dicho/A las pruebas me remito.

In other context yo could use "He dicho" in informal conversation it's kind of a joke maybe when you want to sound softer or not so serious, following with the conversation:

- Exageras, no es para tanto.
- Sí es para tanto, cada día comes más y haces menos ejercicio, estás engordando. He dicho.

Answer (score 2):

The first phrase that comes to mind is:

> A confesión de parte, relevo de prueba

Sometimes shortened to:

> A confesión de parte...

The idea being that if the accused party admits its guilt, there's no need for additional proof (which is pretty much like resting the case, I think).

Answer (score 0):

Aun mas prueba de lo que he dicho.

Lo que he dicho se pruebe.

Concluyo mi alegato.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!